# Force sublime text to use PATH from the shell value

Tags: macos, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am trying to add a simple build system to sublime text 3. Here is my current project configuration :

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings":
    {

    },
    "build_systems":
    [
        {
            "path": "/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Applications/Cocos/tools/ant/bin:/Applications/Cocos/frameworks:/Applications/Cocos/frameworks/cocos2d-x-3.5/tools/cocos2d-console/bin:/Users/shadaen/.rbenv/shims:/Users/shadaen/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:./node_modules/.bin:/Users/shadaen/Library/Haskell/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/shadaen/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin:/opt/nginx/sbin:/Users/shadaen/.bash_it/plugins/available/todo",
            "name": "HybrisHtml5",
            "cmd" : ["./buildAndRunHtml5.sh"]
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see I have put a big path option which reflet the current state of my shell path. (`echo $PATH`)

My question is, is it possible to make sublime text use the current value of `$PATH` in is configuration ?

For information, I am under OSX Yosemite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out that there is a plugin `SublimeFixMacPath` which fix the loaded path by sublime text.